# How to forward sound from a local audio input (USB from a digital piano) to a remote audio output (via a pulseaudio server)?

Tags: linux, audio, debian, pulse-audio

I have 2 PCs under Linux Debian (bullseye) :

- "pc-piano" : where a digital piano is connected via USB, and which has no local audio output
- "pc-desktop" : where my wireless headphones are connected, and which is configured as a pulseaudio server

What I want to achieve is to hear sound produced by the digital piano in my headphones.

- recording audio from the piano locally via Audacity (selecting the right input) on "pc-piano" works
- if I configure "pc-desktop" as default pulseaudio server on "pc-piano" (in `/etc/pulse/client.conf`) I can hear sound from audio files, YouTube videos... played on "pc-piano".
- I tried to enable the loopback module (`pacmd load-module loopback-module latency_msec=5`) but it didn't solve my problem

Basically, what I understand is that if I configure "pc-desktop" as pulseaudio server on "pc-piano", "pc-piano" can use audio inputs and outputs from "pc-desktop". If the digital piano was connected to "pc-desktop", I assume the loopback module would forward the piano sound to my headphones. But I dont understand how to forward a local input to a remote output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts and research, I found a solution that works quite well, but I probably wouldn't use it in reality, and I'll explain why. Nevertheless, it can be interesting for other uses, so I'm sharing the explanation:

1. DO NOT connect "pc-piano" as a client to the pulseaudio server of "pc-desktop." Each machine must have its own pulseaudio server.
2. Create a "tunnel" type "sink" on "pc-piano" by adding these lines to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
.fail
load-module module-tunnel-sink-new sink_name=desktop server=tcp:desktop:4713
.nofail
```

"desktop" is the hostname of "pc-desktop," and 4713 is the default port for pulseaudio.
At this point, after restarting pulseaudio on "pc-piano" (`pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start` with the user account), the various audio configuration/adjustment tools show that the inputs and outputs of both "pc-desktop" and "pc-piano" are usable. This is the key to the solution.

3. Identify the audio input corresponding to the digital piano using the command `pactl list sinks` on "pc-piano." In my case, it is `alsa_output.usb-Yamaha_Corporation_ARIUS-00.analog-stereo`.
4. Load the "loopback" module to redirect the sound from the input corresponding to the digital piano to the previously created "sink" corresponding to the remote pulseaudio server:
   `pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-Yamaha_Corporation_ARIUS-00.analog-stereo sink=desktop latency_msec=1`
   (Note: I assume you can also add this line to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to make it automatic during system startup)
   => At this point, it works! You can hear the notes played on the piano through the audio output of "pc-desktop."

However, this solution is not perfect because, at least in my case, there is a (very slight) delay of about one-tenth of a second between the note played on the piano and the note heard. I'm not sure if this can be improved. It can be a bit annoying, which is why, in the end, I will stick with my trusty old audio cable that runs halfway across my apartment to connect the piano's headphone output to the line input of "pc-desktop." But knowing this solution can be quite useful for other scenarios.